# In a hedge fund, what is a "Partner"?

Tags: terminology, hedge-funds, partnership

I will be meeting with representatives of a hedge fund (doing HFT FX trading), one of whom is titled "Partner".

In the context of a hedge fund, what is the role of a "Partner"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fund is a "[Partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partnership)", a type of legal entity. Partners are akin to shareholders in corporations. In non-limited partnership, each partner has executive authorities. You're probably meeting with one of the decision makers.

Answer (score 0):

The general model of partnership implies that this legal entity is responsible for the overall operations of the fund. So yes, we are talking about decision makers. Limited partners are involved as much as they choose to be, which depends on their investments of course.

The structure of corporations like this one is simply obliged to have at least one GP and one LP, so even if you are not meeting with a GP, that doesn’t mean that you are not talking to a decision maker, or at least an influential partner.

Comment: I've deleted the link from your answer - you've posted it in a couple of places on the SE network, and from a new user it suggests you may be trying to promote something. See http://money.stackexchange.com/help/promotion for some guidance on this.